# How to create a session in spring service class?

Tags: java, spring, session

There is a requirement that I want to create a session object in `Spring` `@Service` class. In the service class only one method is there:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user=appServiceManager.getUser(username);
```

`loadUserByUsername` method will not accept extra parameters anymore - except `username`, as it is calling by predefined class.

I want to keep user details in the session.

How can I get the session in my service class?

Answer (score 1):

`session` object is related to the presentation (View) layer, so It is NOT a best practice to pass the session object to the service layer, rather you need to handle that in your controller itself.

If you handle `session` or `view` related objects in the service layer, you will end up in tightly coupling your service layer (business logic) with the presentation layer, which will be a problem because the whole objective of service layer is to loosely couple with different endpoints (like controller, different web service, etc..).

So you can add `userdetails` into `Httpsession` in controller layer itself like below:

```
@Controller 
public class UserDetailsController {

  public R method1(HttpSession session, UserDetailsBean bean) {

     session.addAttribute("USERDETAILS", bean);

     //you can use UserDetailsBean object anywhere until you remove from session
  }
}
```

If you are using `spring-security`, then you can easily get the `userdetails` in your controller like below:

```
UserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

You can look for API [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)

Comment: actually in i am developing a security application, so from service  the call will be starts by internal class called UserDetailsService. so ..... i will accept with your answer, but i need to keep session there only. ..... the bean will not come to controller..   Is there any way to create a session there????

Comment: UserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();